# How do you detect when a sound file has finished?

Tags: android, while-loop

I am playing a sound file using this code inside a broadcast receiver activity:

```
notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://emad.app/raw/seven_chimes");
```

I would like to detect when this file has finished playing.

I tried a loop like this but I think this is only good for the media player because it always = false even though I made sure the sound file was still playing:

```
/*
 * Stay here until the chime sound is finished.
 */
   while (manager.isMusicActive()){
   }
```

Can you show me what I should use instead of `manager.isMusicActive()`?

Answer (score 140, accepted):

You can use the MediaPlayer class and add a Completion listener to be activated when the sound finishes playing

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this,Uri.parse("android.resource://emad.app/raw/seven_chimes"));

mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        performOnEnd();
    }

});

mp.start();
```

Comment: Hi Ronny, I tried the code but get an error that states: MediaPlayer is not applicable for the arguments (new OnCompletionListener(){}).

Comment: Hi Emad, you need to add import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener; so it will recognize it.

Comment: Hi Ronny, I added the import and had to change "this" to "context" but I still get the same error on the OnCletionListener line. Is something still missing? Thanks. Truly, Emad

Comment: Hi, this is a strange because it's a very strait-forward approche. What is the API version you are using? what is the error message? and what are the Eclipse suggestions when you press control+1 (or command + 1)? you can pass "this" as the argument, mp.setOnCompletionListener(this); and it will suggest you to implement the OnCompletionListener and you can add the onCompletion method to your class. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Hi Ronny, It's for Android 1.6 and is within a broadcast receiver activity. I found I had to also include "import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;" to get it without errors. Thanks so much for the help. Truly, Emad

Answer (score 3):

Not working with broadcast receiver but this is what worked for my current project using Kotlin to track when the audio file has finished playing.

```
playButton.setOnClickListener {

            if (isPlaying) {
                pauseSound()
            }else {
                playSound()
            }

            mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener {
                playButton.text = "Play"
                isPlaying = false
            }
        }
```

isPlaying is boolean, I will explain more if someone is confused. Hope it helps someone else in the future. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

try using service to play the music..
after it play once, then stop your service and you can add your program on the onDestroy() service method..
hope it helps :)

Comment: Hi Michael, I would like to also try your way as well. Can you show a code example for me to try out? Thanks. Truly, Emad