# Playing random sound when ImageButton is clicked on Android

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I'm new in android and I'm trying to play random sound when `ImageButton` is clicked.

I'm still getting the same audio when I press the button. It should play different sounds every time the button is pressed. Also I would like to add a stop button later.

Here is my code:

```
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

import java.util.Random;

public
class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    MediaPlayer mp;
    ImageButton soundbutton;

    int[] sounds = {R.raw.audi, R.raw.berlin, R.raw.bratanki, R.raw.budzik, R.raw.cztery, R.raw.drzyz, R.raw.dziewczyny, R.raw.emeryt, R.raw.enter, R.raw.faza};
    Random r = new Random();
    int rndm = r.nextInt();

    @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //media player

        soundbutton = (ImageButton)this.findViewById(R.id.playButton);
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), sounds[rndm]);
        soundbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                        mp.stop();
                        mp.release();
                        rndm = r.nextInt();
                        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), sounds[rndm]);
                    }
                    mp.start();
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give a maximum to your Random. You have 10 sounds so you want a number between 0-9.

```
rndm = r.nextInt(10);
```

This will give you a number between 0-9.

Comment: It only plays just one sound the whole time app is running after editing to this: ```int[] sounds={R.raw.audi, R.raw.berlin, R.raw.bratanki, R.raw.budzik, R.raw.cztery, R.raw.drzyz, R.raw.dziewczyny, R.raw.emeryt, R.raw.enter, R.raw.faza};

    int rndm = r.nextInt(10);    rndm = r.nextInt(10);
                        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),sounds[rndm]);```

Comment: This should change sounds after each click of the button. If you'd like to continually change sounds once the audio has started playing, you can set an OnCompletionListener explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10529226/notify-once-the-audio-is-finished-playing

Comment: It does not change sound. It is still the same sound, but when I click the button before sound is stopped, then it plays next audio file.

Comment: ok, it works I just moved ```rndm = r.nextInt(9);
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), sounds[rndm]);
        mp.start();``` outside if.