# Play two sound with onClick

Tags: android, audio, media-player

I want to play two different sound file when the user clicks the button

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        playSound(this,R.raw.s1);
        playSound(this,R.raw.s2);

    }

    public static void playSound(Context context, int soundID){      
        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, soundID); 
        mp.start();
        }
```

the problem on this code is the s1 and s2 files are played on the same time , I want to play s1 then if s1 finsh playing s2 file, How can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried to add a CompletionListener to your MediaPlayer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7367997/how-do-you-detect-when-a-sound-file-has-finished

Comment: For this kind of thing I recommend using a `SoundPool` instead of a MediaPlayer (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html)

Comment: @KenWolf Why do you want him to use a SoundPool object ?

Comment: @ZouZou I find it's better for playing short sounds concurrently. I'm guessing the use case is more like sound effects rather than say, two songs playing together. Could be wrong! (https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=mediaplayer+vs+soundpool)

Comment: @KenWolf In this use case, yes you're right =)

Comment: Check the following thread

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10781522/playing-audio-files-one-after-another

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context,R.raw.s1); 
    mp.start();
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() 
    {
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp2){   

            mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(context,R.raw.s2); 
            mp2.start();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int[] sounds = new int[] {R.raw.s1, R.raw.s2};    
int counter = 0;

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    playSound(sounds[counter]);
}

public void playSound(Context context, int soundID){      
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, soundID); 
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    mp.start();
}

@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
    counter++;
    if (counter < sounds.length) {   
        playSound(sounds[counter]);
    }
}
```

Not the most elegant thing I've ever written but it should fulfill your requirement.