# want to move next activity after palying a audio clip (please see image)

Tags: java, android, audio

I am creating a app, where activity move will in the next activity after play a audio clip. but when i wrote the code only audio part is working, next page not coming. i am giving my code. please see image for my codes.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.foood);

    ImageButton btnbreakfast = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.breakfast);

    btnbreakfast.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View V) {
            MediaPlayer audio = MediaPlayer.create(Food.this, R.raw.vada);
            audio.start();
        }
    });
}

public void audio() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Food.this, breakfast.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: provide your code in text format not image..

Comment: Doesn't look like Javascript

Comment: Use inside this method the call to the other activity http://stackoverflow.com/a/7369642/4428183

Comment: check this finish event of `MediaPlayer` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7367997/how-do-you-detect-when-a-sound-file-has-finished

Comment: You are never calling `audio()`. Why are you expecting it to execute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Full code:
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.foood);

    ImageButton btnbreakfast = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.breakfast);

    btnbreakfast.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View V) {
            MediaPlayer audio = MediaPlayer.create(Food.this, R.raw.vada);
            audio.start();
    audio.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    nextScreen();
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

public void nextScreen() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Food.this, breakfast.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: sir, could you edit my code for me. its little urgent.

Answer (score 0):

Add this

```
audio.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        audio(); // call next activity
    }
});
```

after `audio.start();`

**Update**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.foood);
    ImageButton btnbreakfast = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.breakfast);

    btnbreakfast.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View V) {
            MediaPlayer audio = MediaPlayer.create(Food.this, R.raw.vada);
            audio.setOnCompletionListener(mediaListener);
            audio.start();
        }
    });
}

public void audio() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Food.this, breakfast.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener mediaListener = new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        audio(); // call next activity
    }
}
```

Comment: Sir, i will be greatfull if you could edit the full code. i am little confused. please

Comment: Just add the code I have given after `audio.start()` inside `onClick`

Comment: Thanks for your help sir, but it is not happening. i have pasted my codes in text view. will you please edit it for me. thanks in advance

Comment: thank you rohit sir. now the issue is resolved. thank you again

Comment: @ParveenPrajapati: If it works for you then please dont forget to accept the answer.