# Application crashes when button is clicked

Tags: android, button, onclick, audio, android-mediaplayer

I wrote this code in order to make a **soundboard** like app

```
public class ButtonSoundActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private Button buttons[];
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayers[];

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);     
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        releaseSounds();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        initContent();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        releaseSounds();
    }

    /**
     * Initialise all the content :
     * buttons, media players and set click listeners for the buttons
     */
    private void initContent() {
        buttons = new Button[5];
        mediaPlayers = new MediaPlayer[5];

        buttons[0] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button0);
        buttons[1] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        buttons[2] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        buttons[3] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
        buttons[4] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);

        mediaPlayers[0] = MediaPlayer.create(ButtonSoundActivity.this, R.raw.sound1);
        mediaPlayers[1] = MediaPlayer.create(ButtonSoundActivity.this, R.raw.sound2);
        mediaPlayers[2] = MediaPlayer.create(ButtonSoundActivity.this, R.raw.sound3);
        mediaPlayers[3] = MediaPlayer.create(ButtonSoundActivity.this, R.raw.sound4);
        mediaPlayers[4] = MediaPlayer.create(ButtonSoundActivity.this, R.raw.sound5);


        for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
            buttons[i].setOnClickListener(this);
        }      
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        stopSounds();
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
            if(v.getId() == buttons[i].getId()) {
                if(mediaPlayers[i] != null)
                mediaPlayers[i].start();
            }
    }

    /**
     * Stop the previous sound when another button is clicked
     * so that the sounds don't overlap
     */
    private void stopSounds() {
        for(int i=0; i<5 ;i++)
            if(mediaPlayers[i] != null)
            if(mediaPlayers[i].isPlaying()) {
                mediaPlayers[i].pause();
                mediaPlayers[i].seekTo(0);
            }
    }

    /**
     * Release all sounds and empty the mediaPlayers array
     */
    private void releaseSounds() {
        for(int i=0; i<5;i++) {
            if(mediaPlayers[i] != null) {
                mediaPlayers[i].stop();
                mediaPlayers[i].release();
                mediaPlayers[i] = null;                 
            }
        }
    }       
}
```

the xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button0" android:id="@+id/button0"/>

    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button1" android:id="@+id/button1"/>

    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button2" android:id="@+id/button2"/>      

    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button3" android:id="@+id/button3"/>

    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button4" android:id="@+id/button4"/>      
</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is that if I click a button multiple times in a row, the sound doesn't play anymore, or sometime, when I first open the app, it crashes when I click a button.
The error says it's related to the stopSounds method

[error code](http://pastebin.com/NbsGKnyh)

So, does anyone have an answer?

**Edit**: I added the if() before each mediaPlayer element to check if they are null, also I followed this method:

```
            AssetFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.sound1);
        mediaPlayers[0] = new MediaPlayer();

        try {
            mediaPlayers[0].setDataSource(fileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor());
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            mediaPlayers[0].prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

but without any luck :(

**Edit 2**: I got it working :) , I just had to make sure that the *mediaPlayer array* is empty when I *restart* the app. Also I added the *onPause()* and *onResume()* functions.

Comment: There is a NullPointerException on line 57 of your code, what's on this line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting a `NullPointerException` at line 57, inside your `stopSounds` method. Could you post this line all by itself?

Most likely one of the objects in `mediaPlayers` is null. Try stepping through the debugger and see what the array looks like when you first enter the `stopSounds` method.

Comment: ' if(mediaPlayers[i].isPlaying()) {  ' this is the line

Comment: I even checked if it is null '     if(!mediaPlayers[i].equals(null))
 if(mediaPlayers[i].isPlaying()) {
  mediaPlayers[i].pause();
  mediaPlayers[i].seekTo(0);
} '

Comment: As the docs state, [`MediaPlayer.create()` can return null if creation failed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#create%28android.content.Context,%20int%29). Try putting null checks before you try to call methods on the MediaPlayer objects in the array

Comment: That method of checking whether it is null will still throw a NullPointerException if it is null. Use `if (!mediaPlayers[i] == null)` instead

Comment: you are right, thanks! but now, some buttons do not work(the sound does not play anymore), some of them work

Comment: That is due to the MediaPlayer associated with that button being null. Check logcat as it might tell you why creation failed

Comment: yes, some mediaplayer elements are not created :  http://pastebin.com/j46ax0QS  also, line 35 is this: mediaPlayers[2] = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound3);   Could the problem be related to the sounds? Bad encoding?

Comment: That looks like a general error opening the raw resource. I would suggest making sure it can be opened elsewhere, and is not corrupted. Perhaps this question could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3761305/android-mediaplayer-throwing-prepare-failed-status-0x1-on-2-1-works-on-2-2