# Prepare failed.: status=0xFFFFFF8E

Tags: android, media-player

when i use MediaPlayer playing .mp3 file,the system will report error log:

> `Prepare failed.: status=0xFFFFFF8E`

but the playing music is normal,there is not exception.

And according to my observations,as if it come out only in relatively high ROM version,such as 4.0,in 2.3 there is no error.

What is the reason, how to solve?

Comment: Did you call mediaPlayer.prepare() before mediaPlayer.start() ?

Comment: Take a look at 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3761305/android-mediaplayer-throwing-prepare-failed-status-0x1-on-2-1-works-on-2-2