# Why I'm getting Prepare failed.:status=0x1?

Tags: java, android, media-player

I've seen such questions on this site but can't find exact solution for this. I'm creating list view of path of songs stored on my SD card. But when I provide the full path to media player, It gives `Prepare failed: status=0x1`.

I've included `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission to menifest. following is my code.

```
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            Object o = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
            String uri = (String)o;
            //uri = uri.substring();
          //  uri = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();

         try{
             MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
             mp.setDataSource(uri);
             mp.setLooping(true);
             mp.prepare();
             mp.start();
         }
         catch (Exception e){

             Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,uri+"    "+e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }



        }
    });
```

I've set onItemClickListener in listView. And on click, I'm fetching song path to a string and providing to media player.

Sample path which I'm getting on click is:

```
/storage/sdcard0/Download/MY_SONG_NAME.mp3
```

Comment: May be this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/16964824/6676466 Good Luck