# Media Player not work in android and give error in prepare

Tags: android, kotlin, uri, android-mediaplayer

I have the following code

```
val filePath = context.filesDir.path.toString() + "/hello_world.mp3"
val inputStream = WaveUtils.reWriteWaveHeader(response.result)
val size = File(filePath).outputStream().use { inputStream.copyTo(it) }
val file = File (filePath)

Log.i("AMIRA00000" , "size : " + size)
Log.i("AMIRA00000" , "filePath : " + filePath)


val player = MediaPlayer()
player.setDataSource(context , Uri.parse(file.path))
player.prepare()
player.start()
```

the file size has value and the filePath is as following

```
/data/user/0/com.sbs16.ensofia/files/hello_world.mp3
```

which means that the file saved correctly, but the player does not work and give this error

```
java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
```

can anyone please help ?

Comment: did you check this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11977292/2553984

Comment: I have tried two files : https://watson-developer-cloud.github.io/doc-tutorial-downloads/text-to-speech/reference/hello_world.wav , this file does not work, and I have tried this : http://www.music.helsinki.fi/tmt/opetus/uusmedia/esim/a2002011001-e02.wav and it is working, I do not know what is the problem of first file

Comment: maybe it's not encoded correctly or something!

Comment: but it is already working in web , so it should work just like any other wav file

Comment: @y.allam : it seems problem in this format, the file is not running on default music player, put the problem that I have to make it run because I got this encoding from watson api, do you know any alternative to media player or how to open this encoding in android

Comment: did you try https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer? i didn't try it before, but it may help