# My audio player on Android doesn't work - Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, audio

I program C# Android app using Xamarin. I wrote this code:

```
protected MediaPlayer player;
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.layout1);
    this.Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen);

    player = new MediaPlayer();
    player.Reset();
    var fileDescriptor = Assets.OpenFd("MySound.mp3");
    player.SetDataSource(fileDescriptor.FileDescriptor);
    player.Prepare();
    player.Start();
}
```

MySound.mp3 file is direct in the Assets folder. When I run app there is an error:

> Java.IO.IOException
> Message=Prepare failed.: status=0x1

in the line with `player.Prepare();`

What is wrong? Why it's no working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a common exception with MediaPlayer.Prepare() on Android devices. A quick search turned up this:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/15f9c371-1b8d-4927-9555-f40e2829c377/mediaplayer-prepare-failed-stauts0x1?forum=xamarinandroid

Quote by Anonymous:

> Hi, I wasted a lot of time, trying to find a solution to this issue on
> my side too. So I post here, just in case it is helping some people.
> My situation : I wanted to load an audio file from my assets (so not
> registered in my resources). I am using a similar code as Ike Nwaogu,
> except that I am using an AssetFileDescriptor to open my file (in my
> activity class code, so I have access to "Assets") :
>
> ```
> string path = "Audio/myfile.ogg";
> Android.Content.Res.AssetFileDescriptor afd = Assets.OpenFd(path);
> MediaPlayer soundPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
>  
> if (afd != null)
> {
>     soundPlayer.Reset();
>     soundPlayer.SetDataSource(afd.FileDescriptor);
>     soundPlayer.Prepare();
>     soundPlayer.Enabled = true;
>     afd.Close();
> }
> ```
>
> I was failing on the Prepare(). I tried to add the access to external
> storage permissions (but it did make sense since it
> was loaded from my assets directly, I tried just in case).
>
> Just by chance, by seeing other people samples on the forums, I added
> the afd.StartOffset, afd.DeclaredLength to the parameters:
>
> soundPlayer.SetDataSource(afd.FileDescriptor, afd.StartOffset,
> afd.DeclaredLength);
>
> and it worked ... I don't know if it just luck and if is going to fail
> again later or if there is a bug in API ...

According to various sources, using getStartOffset and getLength when setting the DataSource should fix this:

```
player.setDataSource(fileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor(), fileDescriptor.getStartOffset(), fileDescriptor.getLength());
```

Alternatively, here are a few more ideas:
[Android MediaPlayer throwing "Prepare failed.: status=0x1" on 2.1, works on 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3761305/android-mediaplayer-throwing-prepare-failed-status-0x1-on-2-1-works-on-2-2)

https://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/6722/andriod-mediaplayer-prepare-failed-status-0x1

Comment: Ohh yess!! That's working. Thank you for help.